# How to add jrebel to Grails tool suite

Tags: grails, jrebel

Can anybody tell me how to use Jrebel in my project. restarting the server takes so much time and I want to make use of Jrebel.

I read the instructions and I couldn't understand how to do the steps
in Server and project configuration

Help me?? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Grails tools suite and Grails itself do you have? Do you have Grails 2 or Grails 3 ?

Comment: grails 2.4.4   ggts 3.6.4.release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Support Engineer from ZeroTurnaround.

Steps to run JRebel with GGTS 3.6.4. and local server:

1. Install and activate JRebel Eclipse plugin (plugin url: http://update.zeroturnaround.com/update-site). More information at http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/eclipse/
2. From GGTS menu bar, open *Help* -> *JRebel Configuration* -> *Startup* -> select your server checkbox -> *Projects* -> select [image: JRebel] for your project
3. From GGTS menu bar, open *Run* -> *Run Configurations* -> *JRebel* -> select *Enable JRebel agent* checkbox -> *Run*

If you are using remote server, then you should follow this guide: http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/remoteserver/eclipse.html